# Use RegEx in CUDA SDK?

Tags: c, regex, cuda

Does the cuda sdk have `regex.h` or are there specific APIs which implement Regex using CUDA?.

Comment: This may get helpful... https://github.com/bkase/CUDA-grep/blob/master/regex.h

Answer (score 2):

At the time of writing, the CUDA SDK/toolkit does not ship with any of library for parsing regular expressions in device code.

It was suggest in comments that [the CUDA-grep](https://github.com/bkase/CUDA-grep) repository on GitHub might be of some use, although the quality, completeness and providence of that code is completely unknown.

*Note that this answer was added as a community wiki entry to get this question off the unanswered question list*